# using awk to combine multiple line elements into single line

Tags: arrays, awk, while-loop

I have a requirement to convert an input file into something more standardised ready for sql loader to insert into an Oracle 8i database (yes, we're with the times!). The problem is that the file is formatted to list each line element vertically so I need to somehow loop through it and build up a valid line as I progress to create the required output file for loading.

I know it should be relatively achievable but I'm completely new to all things AWK/SED and whilst I've made a modicum of progress from reading through the web sites (such as this one) and some books I bought, time constraints mean I need to ask for some far more expert advice to help me.

I believe I can do what I need by building one or more arrays and then looping through the remainder of the data using a while loop, but whilst I can build the arrays okay, I'm not entirely sure how I can link them together or even if what I'm doing is the best method.

Anyway... enough waffling from me.

This is a small subset of the data file I need to process. It's basically a confirmation of books being shipped to us from a supplier:

```
UNB+UNOA:2+5060096369998:14+[BUYER GLN]:14+150310:0105+000023++DESADV'
UNH+0000001+DESADV:D:96A:UN:EAN005'
BGM+351+[INVOICE NUMBER]'
DTM+137:20150309:102'
DTM+11:20150309:102'
DTM+63:20150310:102'
NAD+BY+[BUYER GLN]::9++[BUYER NAME AND ADDRESS]'
NAD+SU+5060096369998::9++GARDNERS BOOKS LTD.+1 WHITTLE DRIVE:WILLINGDON         DROVE:EASTBOURNE+++BN23 6QH+GB'
NAD+DP+[SHIPPING GLN]::9++[SHIPPING NAME AND ADDRESS]'
CPS+1'
PAC+3++PK'
MEA+PD+AAB+KGM:11'
MEA+PD+HT+MMT:460'
MEA+PD+WD+MMT:310'
MEA+PD+LN+MMT:235'
PCI+33E'
GIN+BJ+305060096368359186'
LIN+1++9780006755227:EN'
PIA+1+0006755224:IB'
IMD+F+BST+:::DOGSBODY/JONES, DIANA WYNNE'
QTY+12:1'
RFF+ON:124705572-15-1'
LIN+2++9780007245826:EN'
PIA+1+0007245823:IB'
IMD+F+BST+:::VINTAGE AFFAIR/WOLFF, ISABEL'
QTY+12:3'
RFF+ON:124705572-62-1'
LIN+3++9780007250608:EN'
PIA+1+0007250606:IB'
IMD+F+BST+:::MYSTERY OF THE BLUE TRAIN COMIC STR'
QTY+12:1'
RFF+ON:124705572-48-1'
PAC+3++PK'
MEA+PD+AAB+KGM:11'
MEA+PD+HT+MMT:460'
MEA+PD+WD+MMT:310'
MEA+PD+LN+MMT:235'
PCI+33E'
GIN+BJ+305060096368359193'
LIN+4++9780091950309:EN'
PIA+1+0091950309:IB'IMD+F+BST+:::LOVER/JORDAN, NICOLE'
QTY+12:1'
RFF+ON:124705572-98-1'
LIN+5++9780099453956:EN'
PIA+1+0099453959:IB'IMD+F+BST+:::FLANDERS PANEL/PEREZ-REVERTE, ARTUR'
QTY+12:1'
RFF+ON:124705572-22-1'
LIN+6++9780099481379:EN'
PIA+1+0099481375:IB'
IMD+F+BST+:::MYSTERIOUS FLAME OF QUEEN LOANA/ECO'
QTY+12:2'
RFF+ON:124705572-36-1'
CNT+1:9'
CNT+2:6'
UNT+695+0000001'
UNZ+1+000023'
```

Ignore the top few lines, the lines I'm really interested in are the lines commencing GIN (these are the individual record identifiers), LIN (contains the book ISBN), QTY (contains qty funnily enough) and RFF (contains our internal reference).

Setting the field separator as [+:]+ I need to commence from each GIN record and retrieve $3 from that line (this is what I'd initially added into my array). Whilst that value remains the same I want to continue through the file and for each LIN record I want to pick up the $3 value from the LIN, QTY and RFF fields and print those out on the same line including the GIN value. Once the GIN record changes we continue as above but now we print out the new GIN value in field 1 of each line. Field separator on the output can be spaces or commas (or anything else really) and ideally I'd like to get rid of the apostrophe ' that appears at the end of each value/line too.

The output would end up something like the below (I've actually included the line identifiers ($1) to make it easier to follow but wouldn't really need them for the final print) :

```
GIN305060096368359186,LIN9780006755227,QTY1,RFF124705572-15-1
GIN305060096368359186,LIN9780007245826,QTY3,RFF124705572-62-1
GIN305060096368359186,LIN9780007250608,QTY1,RFF124705572-48-1
GIN305060096368359193,LIN9780091950309,QTY1,RFF124705572-98-1
GIN305060096368359193,LIN9780099453956,QTY1,RFF124705572-22-1
GIN305060096368359193,LIN9780099481379,QTY2,RFF124705572-36-1
```

I've not added any of my attempts as they are vast and numerous and probably all rubbish. The full file would end up with probably 30 or 40 GIN records with around 30 LIN records for each.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve this :

First you need to know what kind of line it is :

```
is_gin=`echo $i | grep "GIN+"`
is_lin=`echo $i | grep "LIN+"`
is_qty=`echo $i | grep "QTY+"`
is_rff=`echo $i | grep "RFF+"`
```

Then you need specific processing for each of these :

Just take the digit for this one

```
gin=`echo $i | grep -o '[0-9]*'`
```

remove all that is before ++ and take only digit for that is after

```
linreq=`echo $i | sed 's/.*++//g' | grep -o '[0-9]*'`
```

take all digit after : and remove : after

```
qty=`echo $i | grep -o ':[0-9]*' | sed -e 's/://g'`
```

only take the pattern XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX (with as much as X)

```
rff=`echo $i  | grep -o '[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*'`
```

Then that is just a few processing loop and check for new line. Here is your script : `processing.sh input_file output_file`

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' #line delimiter

#empty your output file
cp /dev/null "$2"

for i in $(cat "$1"); do
    
    is_gin=`echo $i | grep "GIN+"`
    is_lin=`echo $i | grep "LIN+"`
    is_qty=`echo $i | grep "QTY+"`
    is_rff=`echo $i | grep "RFF+"`

    if [ ! -z "$is_gin" ]; then
        #gin=`echo $i | grep -o '[0-9]*'`
        gin=`echo $i | awk 'match($0,/[0-9]{1,}/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'`
        newline=0
        linecontent="GIN${gin},"
    elif [ ! -z "$is_lin" ]; then
        #linreq=`echo $i | sed 's/.*++//g' | grep -o '[0-9]*'`
        linreq=`echo $i | sed 's/.*++//g' | awk 'match($0,/[0-9]{1,}/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'`
        if [ -z "$linecontent" ]; then
            linecontent="GIN${gin},LIN${linreq},"
        else
            linecontent="${linecontent}LIN${linreq},"
        fi
    elif [ ! -z "$is_qty" ]; then
        #qty=`echo $i | grep -o ':[0-9]*' | sed -e 's/://g'`
        qty=`echo $i | awk 'match($0,/:[0-9]{1,}/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' | sed -e 's/://g'`
        linecontent="${linecontent}QTY${qty},"
    elif [ ! -z "$is_rff" ]; then
        #rff=`echo $i  | grep -o '[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*'`
        rff=`echo $i  | awk 'match($0,/[0-9]{1,}-[0-9]{1,}-[0-9]{1,}/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'`
        linecontent="${linecontent}RFF${rff}"
        echo $linecontent >> "$2"
        linecontent=""
    fi

done

cat $2
```

Output :

```
GIN305060096368359186,LIN9780006755227,QTY1,RFF124705572-15-1
GIN305060096368359186,LIN9780007245826,QTY3,RFF124705572-62-1
GIN305060096368359186,LIN9780007250608,QTY1,RFF124705572-48-1
GIN305060096368359193,LIN9780091950309,QTY1,RFF124705572-98-1
GIN305060096368359193,LIN9780099453956,QTY1,RFF124705572-22-1
GIN305060096368359193,LIN9780099481379,QTY2,RFF124705572-36-1
```

I added awk notation which works as well to match with your need

gist : https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/771b2371c0050b658fcd

Comment: Hi Bertrand - thanks for the quick reply. Never even thought of just using grep and sed, thank you so much - I'm getting an error at the moment though stating that grep -o isn't a valid option. Could be we're on an older version though so I could look to update.

Comment: Oh maybe you are not on an Unix machine. But dont worry you can replace all grep -o 'regex' with awk 'match($0,/regex/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' if you have access to awk

Comment: I updated my answer to use only awk and no grep. I hope it works for you

Comment: We're on a fairly old flavour of AIX unfortunately but I do indeed have access to awk so I've made the adjustments you suggested and bingo!! Perfectly, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for this Bertrand, can't tell you how appreciative I am for your time and help.

Comment: you are welcome, I'm glad you made it. if your problem is solved you can click on accept this answer

Comment: Just noticed your updated script (thanks again). I actually amended it to 'match($0,/[0-9]+/).....' for GIN/LIN lines, 'match($0,/\:[0-9]+/).....' for the QTY and 'match($0,/[0-9\-]+/.....' for the RFF lines. Sorry to keep picking your brains, I assume your way is cleaner and better but wondered if you could explain what the {1,} element pertains to? Thanks again.

Comment: Sure I use {1,} instead of * because it takes 1 to * number and you can parameter the number of digit you want. If you have an 5 ID digit {1,5} is good